# conditionally replace values in preceding rows in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, conditional-statements

I would like to replace values in previous row(s) conditional on values in other columns.

This is an example of my data that has minutes/day spent in various activities.

```
activity <- c("car","soccer","eat","drink")
category <- c("travel","sport","eat/drink","eat/drink")
duration <- c(75,15,10,160)
df <- data.frame(activity, category,duration)

   activity  category duration
1      car    travel       75
2   soccer     sport       15
3      eat eat/drink       10
4    drink eat/drink      160
```

If in any row, duration of "drink" is > 5 minutes (as it is in row 4), I want to replace "duration" in that row with 5 minutes, and add the remaining time (in this case 155 minutes) to the "duration" value in the preceding row, UNLESS the preceding row has "eat/drink" as its "category", in which case I want to add the remaining time to "duration" of the row before the preceding row...

In the above example, I would add 155 minutes to "duration" in row 2. However, if row 2 also had "eat/drink" as its "category", I would want to add the 155 minutes to the preceding row (row 1).

Thanks for any help!

So far I have tried:

```
df$duration[-nrow(df)] <- ifelse(df$activity[-1]=="drink" & df$duration[-1] > 5, 
                               df$duration + c(df$duration[-1]-5, 0),
                               df$duration)
```

which adds the 155 minutes to the previous row, and gives me this:

```
    activity  category duration
1      car    travel       75
2   soccer     sport       15
3      eat eat/drink      165
4    drink eat/drink      160
```

and then I've simply replaced the duration in row 4 with 5 minutes, like this.

```
df$duration <- ifelse(df$activity =="drink" & df$duration >5,
                      5,
                      df$duration)
```

which gives me this...

```
   activity  category duration
1      car    travel       75
2   soccer     sport       15
3      eat eat/drink      165
4    drink eat/drink        5
```

But I can't work out how to move the 155 minutes to the preceding row (row 2), conditional on it not having "eat/drink" as the category. In that case, I want to move it to the row before, etc...

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I added some of my attempts so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer but unfortunately I didn't manage to make a fuzzy join implying one column on the left side and two on the right side. So there is a cartesian product at some moment (at merge). Your result is in 'df6', variable 'duration2'.

```
activity <- c("car","soccer","eat","drink","car","drink","car","drink")
category <- c("travel","sport","eat/drink","eat/drink","travel","eat/drink","travel","eat/drink")
duration <- c(75,15,10,160,100,50,200,60)
df <- data.frame(activity, category,duration)

df$row<-1:nrow(df)

df1<-df[(activity=="drink")&(duration>5),]
df1$time<-df1$duration-5

library(dplyr)
df2<- df1
df2$row1<-lag(df2$row)
df2<-rename(df2,row2=row)

df$key <-1
df2$key <-1
df3 <- merge(df,df2,by="key") %>% filter(((is.na(row1)&(row<row2)|(row>row1)&(row<row2)))&(category.x!="eat/drink"))
df4 <- df3 %>% group_by(row1) %>% 
    summarize(row=last(row),time=last(time)) %>% select(row,time)
df5 <-      df %>% left_join(df4,by="row") %>% 
    mutate(duration2=ifelse(is.na(time),duration,duration+time)) %>%
    select(activity,category,duration,duration2,row)
df2 <- select(df2,row2,time)
df6 <- df5 %>% left_join(df2,by=c("row" = "row2")) %>% 
    mutate(duration2=ifelse(is.na(time),duration2,duration-time)) %>% 
    select(-time)
df6
#  activity  category duration duration2 row
#1      car    travel       75        75   1
#2   soccer     sport       15       170   2
#3      eat eat/drink       10        10   3
#4    drink eat/drink      160         5   4
#5      car    travel      100       145   5
#6    drink eat/drink       50         5   6
#7      car    travel      200       255   7
#8    drink eat/drink       60         5   8
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas2. The code works fantastic unless there are no situations where activity is "drink" , and duration is ">5". This causes a problem with  `df2$key <-1` , as there are no rows in df2 to be assigned a key=1. I need to run the code by=participant ID, and some participants will not have any "drink" which have duration of ">5". Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Using your code, there is a problem when two consecutive rows contain the activity "drink", with duration ">5". The code will only reallocate the minutes from the uppermost "drink".